# Does The Form Tag Make A Variable Out Of Scope?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have a variable called checker everything is fine until there is a form tag. After that the variable becomes null? Why? and how do I fix it?

```
@{
                                foreach (var f in l)
                                {
                                    var theDate = f.date;
                                    var timeFrom = f.timeFrom;
                                    var timeUntil = f.timeUntil;
                                    var id = f.id;
                                    <div class="col-lg-offset-1"><b><u> Job Available</u></b><br /></div>
                                    <div><b>@theDate.ToLongDateString()</b></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-1"><b>@timeFrom.ToShortTimeString() - @timeUntil.ToShortTimeString()</b></div>
                                        <br />

                                       var checker = false;

                                       foreach (var q in Model.Invitations)
                                       {
                                           if (q.CleanerId == Model.Cleaner.id)
                                           {
                                               checker = true;
                                              <div>@checker</div>
                                           }
                                       }

                                        <form action="/Authentication/TakeJob" method="post" role="form">
                                            <input class="invited" data-invited="@checker" type="hidden" name="invited" value="@checker" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="JobId" value="@id" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="CleanerId" value="@Model.Cleaner.id" />
                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg acceptButton">I'll Take The Job</button>
                                        </form>
                                }
                                }
```

Comment: Could you show the generated markup?

Comment: Is that your entire code? Was there anything you've cutout between the html form and the code above it? I feel like something unrelated is going on - particularly because `checker` is not a nullable boolean.

Comment: Updated the question with all code exactly as is.

Comment: I switched it to a int value and it worked! Who knows why?!?!?!?! But It's working for now. Thanks for trying to help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the position of the closure, there is no need for your scope to be so wide including the form.

```
   @{
    var checker = false;
    foreach (var q in Model.Invitations)
    {
        if (q.CleanerId == Model.Cleaner.id)
        {
           <div>@checker</div>
           //here it works
        }
    }
}
    <form action="/Authentication/TakeJob" method="post" role="form">
          //here it is null 
        <input class="invited" data-invited="@this.checker" type="hidden" name="invited" value="@this.checker" />
        <input type="hidden" name="JobId" value="@id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="CleanerId" value="@Model.Cleaner.id" />
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg acceptButton">I'll Take The Job</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: If the closure doesn't include the form than it doesn't recognize the @checker that's in the form.

Comment: Doesn't seem to recognize it? this doesn't seem to help?